# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'geoprocessing Layer object'

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.3, python-toolbox

I am getting a rather unclear type error, and after searching online I cannot find any solutions that help. I am trying to create my own python toolbox for wifi router signal loss, and I am trying to create a raster based on a few inputs that will populate from an equation. The error that I am getting lies on line 107, which is the equation line

```
fspl= (4 * math.pi * distmod * dist_float * hertz)/(2.99792458 * (10**8))
output_rast = fspl
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this error, initially it did not like me trying to use a raster instead of a float, so I changed the distance raster into a float, and now it does not seem to like the float being part of the equation. Here is the rest of my code incase the error stems from an earlier mistake. I cannot find anything that relates to my specific error, and I have not been able to find any way to to work around this issue.  Any suggestions?

```
import arcpy
import math

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox Label Property"
        self.alias = "Toolbox Alias Property"
    # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
    self.tools = [FSPL, WAP_Buffer]


class FSPL(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Free Space Path Loss"
        self.description = "This python script tool will create Free Space Path Loss to determine the dB range output from the WAPs."
        self.canRunInBackground = False

def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""

    param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Wireless Access Points",
    name="wireless_pts",
    datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

    param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Network Frequency Type",
    name="network_freq",
    datatype="String",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")
    param1.filter.type="ValueList"
    param1.filter.list = ["2.4 GHz", "5 GHz"]

    param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Distance Raster Float",
    name="dist_float",
    datatype="GPLayer",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")

    param3 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Distance Raster Units",
    name="units",
    datatype="String",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Input")
    param3.filter.type="ValueList"
    param3.filter.list = ["Feet", "Meters"]

    param4 = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Output Raster",
    name="output_rast",
    datatype="GPRasterLayer",
    parameterType="Required",
    direction="Output")

    return [param0, param1, param2, param3, param4]

def isLicensed(self):
    """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
    return True

def updateParameters(self, parameters):
    """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal
    validation is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter
    has been changed."""


    return

def updateMessages(self, parameters):
    """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
    parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
    return

def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""

    #Get inputs
    wireless_pts = parameters[0].value
    network_freq = parameters[1].value
    dist_float = parameters[2].value
    units = parameters[3].value
    output_rast = parameters[4].value

    #Create expression

    if network_freq == "2.4 GHz":
        hertz=2400000000
    else:
        hertz=5000000000

    if units == "Feet":
        distmod=0.3048
    else:
        distmod=1

    #equation

    fspl= (4 * math.pi * distmod * dist_float * hertz)/(2.99792458 * (10**8))
    output_rast = fspl



    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raster Calculator is an option but limits what you can do. When using arcpy, you must convert your raster dataset to a [raster object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000051000000) to perform [map algebra](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00p600000008000000).

When [defining the parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001500000035000000) in a python toolbox, it may be sufficient to change the data type to GPRasterLayer or GPRasterDataset.  Otherwise, just cast the path of the raster to a raster object with Raster().